# How do I answer WebSocket client's handshake

Tags: websocket, embedded, stm32

I am trying to create a simple webSocket server on STM32 board. I have a simple html/js webpage which is trying to connect to my server. It is sending client's handshake, which I parse on server. It does all needed procedures to create answer and specifically sec-websocket-accept. This is how request and response look like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: IP
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.136 YaBrowser/20.2.2.177 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://192.168.1.61
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Key: PswqFRjY8rupf+Gq8/Cndw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: XhywTKBnx/pq+hEDH66h7tZBArk=
```

I don't know if my browser can't see this response or it just doesn't accept connection, but I know that response is sent to browser's ip/port, I can track it with Wireshark. The response is formed correctly with all needed /r/n and repeating myself, the encoding is done right. Am I missing something or what kind of problem may I have?

Comment: Looks ok. Do you have 2 `\r\n` at the end?

Comment: I have \r\n at the end of the accept header and then another \r\n

Comment: The issue can be in a few different places. What does the server do with the socket after the connection? On the client side, does the Javascript code keep the socket open? How do you know things are failing? Find a plugin or test site for the client side so you don't have to worry about that until you know the server is working.

Comment: The client is just doing new WebSocket and alerting event that new WebSocket has returned. To be precise, any time I try to establish connection it alerts an error. Js doesn't close socket at any time and if it is the case will alert that connection is closed.

Comment: @BlackLenin Did you figure it out? I'm in the same situation